# Does Windows XP only allows 10 inbound TCP/IP connections at any one time?

Tags: windows-xp, web-server

Does Windows XP only allow 10 inbound TCP/IP connections at any one time ?

I am trying to connect 40 clients to my webservice on Windows-XP

and i get no connection

Comment: @nick ... yes it does. @Gali the reason is that they don't want you to use a Client OS as a server... so why are you trying to server 40 clients with window xp ?!?!?!

Comment: Duplicate on SuperUser http://superuser.com/questions/309271/does-windows-xp-only-allow-10-inbound-tcp-ip-connections-at-any-one-time

Comment: Closing as off topic, please see duplicate Dave linked to above

Answer (score 10):

No. The limit is 10 connections for SMB file/print/IPC, not general purpose TCP/IP connections.

Comment: Includes IIS too

Comment: He's talking webservice, which probably means IIS.

Answer (score 5):

The default connection limit for IIS on Windows XP is 10 connections. This can be increased to 40 connections, but not higher than that.

From http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive/2003/10/10/31476.aspx:

> Find the adsutil.vbs script (should be in c:\inetpub\AdminScripts or
>   similar) and run the following command:
>
> adsutil set w3svc/MaxConnections 40

Besides the obvious answer of purchasing a Server OS, you might be able to use Apache for Windows (if you aren't running ASP.net apps), since I believe it does not have the same limit that IIS has.

Comment: Just because you can increase the limit, doesn't mean you should. Check out the EULA for XP Pro sometime. It clearly states a 10 connection limit meaning that even if it is technically possible to accept more than 10 connections, it's not legally acceptable to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [The limit is 10 inbound connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314882).

Comment: That's for Windows Networking though, not for plain-jane non-Windows-auth TCP connections.